# Problems when routing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im writing an app that the user can update their plan data on a view.

My route its like this:

```
  get '/account/plans', to: 'accounts#plans'
  post '/account/change_plan', to: 'accounts#change_plan'
  get '/account/change_plan', to: 'accounts#plans'
```

On my controller i have:

```
#accounts_controller.rb
  def change_plan
    @plan = Plan.find(params[:plan])
    current_user.plan = @plan
    current_user.save
    render 'payment_options'
  end
```

and in my view I have:

```
 <div class="plan-details">
    <header class= <%= plan.css %> >
      <h3><%= plan.name %></h3>
      <small><%= plan.visibility %></small>      
      <p><%= plan.card_description.html_safe %></p>
      <span class="plan-price"><sup>$</sup><%= plan.amount.to_s %></span>
    </header>
    <article>
     <%= plan.features_description.html_safe %>
      <%= link_to button_text,  account_change_plan_path, title: button_text, :class=>"btn btn-md btn-block btn-outline-green" %>
    </article>
 </div><!-- end plan details -->
```

But when I press this button it show me the message:

```
No route matches [GET] "/account/change_plan"
```

Why when I press the button, on the server log it says:

```
Processing by AccountsController#plans as HTML
```

and not
    Processing by AccountsController#change_plan as HTML

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things going on here, it looks like.

You are using link_to for your submit button, instead of a form submit button. By default link_to makes GET requests. You need to tell it to submit a POST request instead, since that is what your route is defined as.

Change

```
<%= link_to button_text,  account_change_plan_path, title: button_text, :class=>"btn btn-md btn-block btn-outline-green" %>
```

To

```
<%= link_to button_text,  account_change_plan_path, method:  :post, title: button_text, :class=>"btn btn-md btn-block btn-outline-green" %>
```

See https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html for how to use link_to.

Secondly, your route does not have a parameter for 'plan' in it, and you aren't sending one over with your link_to, so even after you fix your link_to, your action won't be able to find the plan. You should change your route to be:

```
post '/account/change_plan/:plan', to: 'accounts#change_plan'
```

And then change your link_to to be (assuming you are using plan.id as your plan identifier):

```
<%= link_to button_text,  account_change_plan_path(plan.id), method:  :post, title: button_text, :class=>"btn btn-md btn-block btn-outline-green" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined your route as `POST` but your link is doing a `GET`.

This should work:

`<%= link_to button_text, account_change_plan_path(plan_id: plan.id), title: button_text, class: "btn btn-md btn-block btn-outline-green", method: :post %>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to call as POST action and pass `plan` params `{plan: plan.id}`

```
<%= link_to button_text, 
    account_change_plan_path({plan: plan.id}), 
    method: :post, 
    title: button_text, 
    class: "btn btn-md btn-block btn-outline-green" %>
```